# create a balloon popup in taskbar using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function that will produce a balloon popup in the
taskbar using javascript.

Is it possible? Whats the shortest and easiest way to do this?

or else what will be the available method..

Thanks.

Comment: From a webpage? No.  Do you mean using WSH?

Comment: By 'Taskbar' do you mean the system taskbar at the bottom (or other edge) of the screen?

Comment: What system? What environment? From a browser? (Can't do, can't go outside of browser's window) From WSH? From another application?

Answer (score 6):

The closest you could get is to make one fixed to the bottom of the viewport of the browser. You could tailor it to appear as though it were part of the windows chrome, but this does tend to annoy users, who don't appreciate attempts to 'fool' them into believing a dialogue/popup/whatever is coming from their OS when it actually isn't.

See: [Jeff Atwood on the horrors of fake interfaces](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001164.html)

Answer (score 1):

Impossible from a browser.  And a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

eum.. no ?

Wouldn't be cross-platform anyway. Just don't try to do things outside of the browser.   Internet explorer can eventually let you, the others not.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably come pretty close with [jGrowl](http://www.stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html).  But you'll have to reset the position to bottom-right (it defaults to top-right).

Answer (score 1):

The [Yahoo Widget Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Widgets) (previously called Konfabulator) allowes to do so; you'll be not in a browser anymore, but in a lightweight web-based desktop application, which probably is rather what you want anyway.

Anybeast from a webpage should never ever leave it's frame/browser.